# Auto-complete field not working

Tags: ajax

Auto-complete field not working. I am getting the result in the dropdown box but unable to select any dropdown option.
This is the code:-

```
function _questionnaire_autocomplete($string = '') {
  $matches = array();
  $result = db_select('questionnaire', 'q')
    ->fields('q', array('title'))
    ->condition('title', '%' . db_like($string) . '%', 'LIKE')
    ->execute();


  // save the query to matches
  foreach ($result as $row) {
    $matches[$row->questionnaire_add] = check_plain($row->title);
  }

  //echo "<pre>";print_r($result);exit;
  // Return the result to the form in json
  drupal_json_output($matches);
}
```

help needed.

Comment: Can you add the form field code as well?

Comment: Where does `$row->questionnaire_add` come from? You're not selecting that column...